# How to use the variable that I create in jquery

Tags: jquery, performance

```
var apptHour = $('select[name="ctl00$m$g_20abfee5_53b6_4db3_b243_ae9b79cab374$ctl00$ctl05$ctl09$ctl00$ctl00$ctl04$ctl00$ctl00$DateTimeField$DateTimeFieldDateHours"]').val();
var endHour = $('select[name="ctl00$m$g_20abfee5_53b6_4db3_b243_ae9b79cab374$ctl00$ctl05$ctl11$ctl00$ctl00$ctl04$ctl00$ctl00$DateTimeField$DateTimeFieldDateHours"]').val();


$('apptHour').blur(function() {
    $('endHour').val($(this).val());
});
```

This doesn't seem to work.  I also tried that and it still doesn't work.

```
$apptHour.blur(function() {
    $endHour.val($(this).val());
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Why on earth you do you use such a names for select boxes?

Comment: I got that long name from SharePoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually `apptHour` and `endHour` are already elements.
So you just do

```
apptHour.blur(function() {
endHour.val($(this).val());
}
```

Comment: Ahh you're right, didn't scroll to the end :D. wll then remove `.val()` you blur the element not its value

Answer (score 1):

Select element first then get the value:

```
var apptHourEl = $('select[name="ctl00$m$g_20abfee5_53b6_4db3_b243_ae9b79cab374$ctl00$ctl05$ctl09$ctl00$ctl00$ctl04$ctl00$ctl00$DateTimeField$DateTimeFieldDateHours"]');
var apptHour = appHourEl.val();

var endHourEl = $('select[name="ctl00$m$g_20abfee5_53b6_4db3_b243_ae9b79cab374$ctl00$ctl05$ctl11$ctl00$ctl00$ctl04$ctl00$ctl00$DateTimeField$DateTimeFieldDateHours"]');
var endHour = endHourEl.val();
```

Then:

```
apptHourEl.blur(function() {
    endHourEl.val( this.value );
}
```

Don't confuse value with the element itself.

Comment: `endHour.val();` should be `endHourEl.val();` otherwise +1

Answer (score 1):

```
var apptHour = $('select[name="ctl00$m$g_20abfee5_53b6_4db3_b243_ae9b79cab374$ctl00$ctl05$ctl09$ctl00$ctl00$ctl04$ctl00$ctl00$DateTimeField$DateTimeFieldDateHours"]'),
    endHour  = $('select[name="ctl00$m$g_20abfee5_53b6_4db3_b243_ae9b79cab374$ctl00$ctl05$ctl11$ctl00$ctl00$ctl04$ctl00$ctl00$DateTimeField$DateTimeFieldDateHours"]');

apptHour.blur(function() {

   endHour.val(apptHour.val());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
apptHour.blur(function() {
endHour.val($(this).val());
```

But you could have chosen better tags.

Comment: I have a question, instead of that long name
I thought of using 
var apptHour = $("label:contains('Appointment Date Hours')").next().val();

but I don't think I can use blur with labels.